# the sum of cells that meet a greater than and less than criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the sum of a range/set of cells... if those cells meet two criteria.

I have two columns with specific dates:

```
start(J)       end(K)
12/4/2017   12/10/2017
12/11/2017  12/17/2017
```

I have a date column with numerous dates:

```
Date
14-Dec-17
etc
```

and lastly a column with a value:

```
 Value
 12.5
```

What I want to achieve is if a cell under the date column is >= the start date and is <= to the end date in the same row. I want to take the value in the value column on the same row as the date and calculate the sum of the value cell data if the date data matches the criteria.

if ("date1" >= "start1" && "date1" <= "end1")
than if true take cell value for "value1" in the same row as the "date1"
and sum together all the values for dates that meet the criteria and return the sum.

That's the best I can think to explain what I am trying to achieve. I would like to do this using a formula if possible.

So the first formula I came up with is this:

```
=IF(AND(E$15:E$218>J15,E$15:E$218<K15),SUBTOTAL(9,H$15:H$218),0)
```

this returns zeros for every row except one and that one looks like if summed all the value in the "value" range and returned.

I am currently trying to see if I can use a SUMIFS formula with no luck yet.

Any suggestions on how I can or if its possible to achieve this using a formula. My data is also in a table if that makes a difference. I can put data in standard spreadsheet if needed.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Solution as provided by Scott Craner:

```
Date    Unit Value  Daily EV            Week Start  Week End        Weekly Total
14-Dec-17   0.57    1.71                12/4/2017   12/10/2017      0
14-Dec-17   0.65    0.65                12/11/2017  12/17/2017      2.36
```

in my case the daily EV is the "value" I wanted to sum if the "date" fell between "week start" and "week end"...."weekly total" being the sum of all "daily EV" values that fell between those dates

Comment: Can you provide a dummy example of the desired output?

Comment: The SUMIFS formula given by Scott gave the desired output. I was looking for a sum value so ex: 60.5, or 12.98, etc of all the values where if the corresponding date value fell between start date and end date would be added together. I will update question with answer example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(H$15:H$218,E$15:E$218,">" & J15,E$15:E$218, "<" & K15)
```

Comment: thank you, I was almost there with the SUMIFS formula. thank you again!!